# Slow ajax communication

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have a page and on this page I have a button. When a user clicks on the button it makes an ajax call and renders a graph.

This is a Ruby on Rails project.

```
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",// GET in place of POST
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  url: "/example/test",
  data : {ids_graph: ids_to_graph},
});
```

Server side:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.js
end
```

This ajax call can return 3 arrays with 50k position each, the objective is to render a graph. How I can improve the communication between client and server?

Comment: On the server side you reduce the number of data sent back to the client. I.e, data for a whole year, you return data once a week instead of every day. This is similar to pagination.

Comment: Please add the controller code for the action that responds to this request.